# Postgis query to sort geometries by latitude

Tags: postgis, sql, order

I am looking for an efficient way to get geometries sorted by their latitude (northmost in case of polygons) when querying a postGis database

Something that could work in an order by clause which possibly works independent of the geometry type (as long as the CRS is lat/lon based)

I think the following would be the ideal writing for it

```
order by ST_North(geometry)
```

but I am not aware of such an operator

Answer (score 4):

So far I could think of computing the bounding box and getting its maximum Y value like in:

```
order by ST_YMax(Box2D(geom))
```

PS: Actually the conversion to a box is not necessary and to sort from north to south desc works like a charm, hence the final query part is

```
order by ST_YMax(geom) desc
```

Comment: You can use ST_YMax directly without building Box2D `ST_YMax(geom) from table`

Comment: You are right, I did not notice it does not require converting the geometry. Then I guess it is exactly the operator I am looking for to sort results.

Comment: PostgreSQL calls this an implicit cast, where the type is automatically converted to match another type used by the function. You can see that the geometry->box2d cast is marked `IMPLICIT` to enable this handy feature.